# Submit form from Backend in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I need help I R & D many contact form plugin's but not found any one working
My requirements are I want contact form to be submitted by Front end as well as backend

```
[contact-form-7 id="345"]
```

If I used this above shortcode in backend it display error
Please Help

Is their any way to add new tab on contact form 7 plugin and submit contact form 7 from admin dashboard

Thank You For Help In advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all insert a contact form shortcode into your template file directly. You will need to pass the code into `do_shortcode()` function.
For Example:
`<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="345"]'); ?>`

Comment: This display's the form but doesnot save data and if save where do I check that

Comment: Please Tell me what the error display after clicking on submit button?